# Windows batch file, save contents of file dowloaded by wget to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, wget

Currently, I have a batch file that uses wget to read a file from the server.  Is there any way for wget to save the contents of that file to a variable and then for the batch file to take a certain action based on the value of the variable?

The peseduo-code would probably look something like this.  I am very new to batch files and am still learning the semantics:

```
SAVE RESULT OF wget http://www.theserver.com/instruction TO VARIABLE: the_variable
IF %the_variable% == 'restart' <DO SOME ACTION HERE>
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a possibility using FOR, but I need to know the contents of the file downloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will base this answer on the assumption that your downloaded file contains text strings.
If this is the case then it is possibile to use the FOR command in this way:

```
for /F %I IN (instruction.txt) DO if %I==restart @echo RESTART FOUND
```

This command opens the file "instruction.txt" and parse it assigning each word to the variable %I
Then for each value of variable %I executes the command specified after the keyword DO.
In this case I have compared the variabile %I to the string "restart" and if the result is true the batch execs the command @echo RESTART FOUND

Comment: I assumed that I could save the contents directly to a variable, but indeed the only solution I could find was to save the contents to a file and then read the file.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GOTO: function in your batch file. So that if the variable is equal to a certain value/string it jumps to a particular section in the batch file and carries out the code in that section.

Almost like using methids in Object Orientated Programming.

CHeck this link out :-

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/goto.php

Comment: What I don't know how to do is get the contents into the variable to begin with.